# is this possible to track all the changes like (DML operations) from a single trigger on many tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to track all the changes from the entire table of a database and insert the changes data/activity into the given table by creating a single trigger

```sql
CREATE TABLE sh_audit(
  new_name varchar2(30),
  old_name varchar2(30),
  user_name varchar2(30),
  entry_date varchar2(30),
  operation  varchar2(30)
)

..from entire table
SELECT tablename
FROM all_tables;
```

Comment: no you ave to make the trigger for all tables that need it

Comment: I suggest you consider [Oracle GoldenGate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/goldengate/index.html) if you want a log of all data changes on all tables.